# 1151: A conflict exists with definition mcPlayer in namespace internal

Tags: actionscript-3

Every time I try to run my ActionScript 3 program, I get this error:

> 1151: A conflict exists with definition mcPlayer in namespace internal.

Here is my script:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Knight extends MovieClip
    {
        var mcPlayer:MovieClip;

        public function Knight()
        {
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDown)
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUp)
        }

        private function keyUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            trace(e.keyCode)

        }

        private function keyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void
        {

        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand things correct, your Library contains some object with class **Knight** and inside this object there's a child **MovieClip** of instance name **mcPlayer**. The thing is, all designed elements go to namespace **public**, while all the class fields/methods with no explicitly stated namespaces go to **internal**.

Always declare designed elements as **public**:

```
        public var mcPlayer:MovieClip;
```