# Error with action script compiler error

Tags: actionscript-3

Im making an app in abode flash. With the Code snippest. Im making photo gallery slide right and left and im getting the error.

[image]

**This is my script**
[image]

Need Help or Suggestion to get out of that error. Thanks

Comment: You already have this variable **slideCounter** declared on the same timeline, most probably a **MiovieClip/TextField** with the same instance name designed somewhere in these 1000 frames of yours: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43842899/4687633

Comment: @Organis how to find and delete that error. Im not much good in coding

Comment: Maybe you have a TextField on the stage with th einstance name slideCounter? Probably the one that should show the slide count :) If you can't find it try to rename "slideCounter" everywhere in your script to something else, for example "mySlideCounter"